# SonarQube scanning too much after upgrade to 6.3

Tags: c#, character-encoding, sonarqube, upgrade, sonarqube-scan

I tried searching but haven't found an answer. I upgraded SonarQube from 5.6 to 6.3 by taking the steps outlined here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading
SonarQube was upgraded and up and running quick enough, but then some problems occured. New results weren't being imported for alot of projects and even if they are, things aren't looking good.

The broken importing seems to be related to character set differences. I get crashes like: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read the source file : 'D:/Builds1/SF/CA AanvraagData/Sources/AAHG.AanvraagData.Client/AAHG.AanvraagData.Client.snk' with the charset : 'UTF-8'.
However, I only have the latest C# plugin installed as language plugin. Why is SonarQube even trying to read .snk files? I never had this problem before, and from what I understand SonarQube should only import known filetypes (sonar.import_unknown_files is set to it's default of false). I can manually exclude alot of extensions, but I'd rather not.

The few projects that actually get imported seem to have issues which presenting C# code in testclasses (no syntax coloring). Also the sonarqube runner gives alot of errors like this: Unable to TFS annotate the following file which is not in a mapped TFS workspace. A little further on in the output the annotating does seem to work for the same file all of a sudden. Also, I'm getting debug lines saying stuff like this: 'ontwikkel.config' indexed with language 'null'. Again.. why is it trying to index files other than .cs? Havent looked at these issues since they're minor in comparison which entire projects not importing, but if anyone has a suggestion that would be great.

Things I tried:
- Updating the scanner to the latest version (2.2), but that isnt helping. Reverted back to 2.0
- Manually excluding files - seems to be working to some extend, but I do not want to rely on this. I'm working with 60 other developers..
- Checking upgrade notes to see if I missed anything
- Checking jira for known issues, but I don't really know what to look for

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks!

With regards,

Whistler

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in SonarQube 6.3 which results in the behavior I'm describing, resulting in projects failing to import when using in/exclusions: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8995